# Replace script URL though the console

Tags: javascript, dom, console

i'm trying to update my TinyMCE script URL front the frontend without any kind of ftp access using some kind of injection script.

Currently my page loads this in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

My question is how can I update the src URL and then have it loaded into the page all through the DOM console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create script tag using javascript in console using the following code:

```
var js = document.createElement('script'); 
js.async = true;
js.src = "js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js";
document.body.appendChild(js);
```

and if you want to update it you already have it's reference so you can update it using

```
js.src = "somethingelse.js";
```

Hope that helps....

Answer (score 3):

You can add Id Attribute In script tag and use Dom,

```
    <script id="tiny" type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
        <script>
function changeSrc(){
        var tinytag = document.getElementById("tiny");
        tinytag.setAttribute("src", "js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js");
}
    </script>
```